# In Node/sqlite3, does run's first callback parameter return Error?

Tags: typescript, node-sqlite3

I'm fairly certain I'm using relatively new versions of sqlite3 (5.0.11) and @types/sqlite3 (3.1.8) but the types are not matching the behavior.

Roughly, it seems as though despite `@types/sqlite3/index.d.ts` including this declaration:

`run(sql: string, params: any, callback?: (this: RunResult, err: Error | null) => void): this;`

`err` is the first parameter.

What's going on here?

**Details:**

```
const db: sqlite3.Database;
this.db.run('DELETE from ... (actually it's invalid SQL)', (result: RunResult, err: Error) => {...});
```

This is what `result` contains:

```
Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: ANY {errno: 1, code: 'SQLITE_ERROR', stack: 'Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: ANY', message: 'SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: ANY'}
code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'
errno: 1
message: 'SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: ANY'
stack: 'Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: ANY'
```

I don't know how `Error` is really supposed to look, but this looks more like type `Error` than type `RunResult`.

This is how I invoke the database:

```
if (params !== undefined) {
  this.db.run(sql, params, cb);
} else {
  this.db.run(sql, cb);
}
```

And this is `cb`:

```
const cb = (result: RunResult, err: Error | null) => {
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
  } else {
    resolve(result);
  }
};
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Maybe you have mismatched versions and they updated the callback parameters in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Declaring `this` in a function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function) tells typescript the type of `this` in the function body, it does not get added to the function parameters.

```
function cb(this: RunResult, err: Error | null) {
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
  } else {
    resolve(this); // `this` will be the RunResult
  }
}
```

The above function is still a function will a single parameter `err`, we have just told typescript the type of `this` in the function body. This does not work for arrow functions

Comment: I just realized how that sentence could be read two ways. ;)